# Comparing two GeoDataFrames that are written using different drivers

Tags: geopandas, file-geodatabase, geopackage, fiona

I'm trying to write one of the GeoDataFrames available with the GeoPandas package to a File GeoDataBase, read this back into memory, and then measure equality across these two GeoDataFrames. For some reason, it looks like the geometries are getting modified when going from gdf to gdb. I can't see any visible differences in the geometries across each dataset.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from geopandas.testing import assert_geodataframe_equal
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon

# Create a GeoDataFrame and save it to the File GeoDatabase
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# Remove columns that cause test failure...
gdf1 = gdf1.drop(columns="gdp_md_est")

# Promote Polygon to MultiPolygon to avoid issues writing to gdb
gdf1["geometry"] = [
    MultiPolygon([feature]) if isinstance(feature, Polygon) else feature
    for feature in gdf1["geometry"]
]

# Write gdf to File GeoDataBase
gdf1.to_file("test.gdb", layer="test_fc", driver="OpenFileGDB", precision=15)

# Read File GeoDataBase back into memory
gdf2 = gpd.read_file("test.gdb", layer="test_fc")

# Compare each gdf for differences
print(gdf1.compare(gdf2))

# This throws an error:
assert gdf2.equals(gdf1)
```

```
                                              geometry                                                   
                                                  self                                              other
0    MULTIPOLYGON (((180.00000 -16.06713, 180.00000...  MULTIPOLYGON (((180.00000 -16.06713, 180.00000...
1    MULTIPOLYGON (((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1...  MULTIPOLYGON (((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1...
2    MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.66559 27.65643, -8.66512 27...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.66559 27.65643, -8.66512 27...
3    MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.84000 49.00000, -122.9742...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.84000 49.00000, -122.9742...
4    MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.84000 49.00000, -120.0000...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.84000 49.00000, -120.0000...
..                                                 ...                                                ...
172  MULTIPOLYGON (((18.82982 45.90887, 18.82984 45...  MULTIPOLYGON (((18.82982 45.90887, 18.82984 45...
173  MULTIPOLYGON (((20.07070 42.58863, 19.80161 42...  MULTIPOLYGON (((20.07070 42.58863, 19.80161 42...
174  MULTIPOLYGON (((20.59025 41.85541, 20.52295 42...  MULTIPOLYGON (((20.59025 41.85541, 20.52295 42...
175  MULTIPOLYGON (((-61.68000 10.76000, -61.10500 ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-61.68000 10.76000, -61.10500 ...
176  MULTIPOLYGON (((30.83385 3.50917, 29.95350 4.1...  MULTIPOLYGON (((30.83385 3.50917, 29.95350 4.1...

[177 rows x 2 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/reprex.py", line 30, in <module>
    assert gdf2.equals(gdf1)
AssertionError
```

Comment: Maybe try some more targeted testing https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.testing.assert_geodataframe_equal.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give this a look.